# How to create appxbundle that does not require developer license

Tags: win-universal-app, sideloading

I am working with the infrastructure team on deploying a Windows 10 Universal app and running into some roadblocks.  They are currently requesting a release version application that does not require a developer license to install.  They are using SCCM, a tool that I am not familiar with, and are only being presented with OS requirements of Windows 10 Mobile (not Windows 10 (x86), (x64)) and are on hold until I solve the developer license issue.
Here is what I have done:

- Create appx bundle via Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- I chose that it will NOT be uploaded to the store
- Used x86 and x64 in release mode for the configuration
- License used from a domain CA for code signing and appears to work
- Enabled "Allow all trusted apps to install" in local GP editor (my dev device)
- Enabled sideloading in settings/update & security/for developers

When running the Powershell script, I am greeted with "Before installing this app, you need to do the following: - Acquire a developer license" and then it does some administrator prompting and cannot acquire a developer license.

If I put the device in developer mode, the script runs flawlessly and the application runs as expected.

Am I missing something that is causing me to require a developer license?  Does it have anything to do with the package folder ending in _Test?  It is the only output that it creates.

If I can provide any additional information, let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: If you follow the steps in [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt269549.aspx) do any fail?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I believe I have done all of that.  The one point that sticks out that I'll have to verify tomorrow is how the cert was imported.  I let it auto select where to put it - perhaps it was not the trusted root.  I will post back when tested.  Thanks again!

Comment: I ensured the certificate was in the Trusted Root Certification folder... still prompts for developer license.  I have our infrastructure team looking into how they created the cert.  Will post back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK... I finally figured it out.  It was nothing to do with the configuration or the app packaging.  It was the Visual Studio 2015 generated PowerShell script that was requiring the developer license (Developer Mode).  If I simply ran my own **Add-AppxPackage *PathToAppxBundle*** in PowerShell, it installed without certificate or developer prompt in Sideload mode.  Note that the certificate is already installed via group policy in my case.

Comment: To expand on this a little; There's a function in Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 called CheckIfNeedDeveloperLicense. I was able to put return $false and and my appx installed fine.

Comment: After modifying the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file i get an error from powershell: \Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 is not digitally signed. Did you get it too? Am i missing something?